# How to prevent a big html table to be loaded everytime the site is visited? (Using datatables, a jQuery plugin)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm developing the CRUD for a back-end tool and I'm using DataTables (a jQuery plugin that helps handling HTML tables) to display the list of elements of each row along with the view, edit and remove options. The tables are about 4,000 rows and the loading time is about 7 seconds. I tried server-side processing and got almost no improvement, I also setted

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

and that didn't help either.

The problem is that after clicking view/edit and going back to the table it reloads taking 7 seconds again.

In the solution I'm thinking about, only the first load takes those 7 seconds, and afterwards it should load intantaneously. (I'll provide an option to refresh in case the user wants to see any changes). The problem is I don't know how to do this.

If you think my idea is good can you help me with the solution? if not, then what should I do?

PS: Does 7 second loading time for a 4,000 row table sounds right? or am I doing something else wrong?

PS2:  I'm developing using PHP and no framework.

Thank you very much for your help!

**UPDATE:**

I partially solved the problem, for displaying big tables I used [Deferred Rendering](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/defer_render.html) which works lighting fast! BUT I don't know how to store links in the DataTables' aaData array (I don´t know if it's even posible, if it is please let me know). On the other hand what was really causing the table rendering to slow down was that I had 3 buttons for each row (View/Edit/Delete) So I removed them and I'm using only a view link, now the table loads in about 2 seconds.

Comment: Mate read a little about JavaScript AJAX techniques. If the user changes a field, you can make that request to server by AJAX, and then you can change just the field that has been changed using client side (so, the entirely table doesn't need to be reloaded).

Comment: Why not simply download only the table elements to view and page the results? Then you're NEVER downloading 4000 elements; maybe 20 at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I'm reading a posible neat solution using the plugin I mentioned, If that works I'll post it here, if not I'll try what you've suggested and read some more AJAX. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Limit the rows to 10-25-50-100-500-1000-2000-4000 per page. So if the user wants to view all results, let the user choose that how much does he/she want display. (something similar to stackoverflow's system)

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using the default settings which allows pagination and limits the rows to 100 per page. The problem is that DataTables loads the entire data to allow using features like filtering.

Comment: Check this topic: http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/83/how-to-pagination-with-ajax/p1
You could receive the paging on server side with a parameter (yoursource.php?page=2) and then populate the DataTable with the results.